# How to write laravel model based in this query with pagination?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($keyskill); $i++) {
                    if ($i == count($keyskill) - 1) {
                        $key .= "skills like '%" . $keyskill[$i] . "%' ";
                    } else {
                        $key .= "skills like '%" . $keyskill[$i] . "%' or ";
                    }
                }
```

Hear my Query is

```
$jobs = DB::select("SELECT * from post where ( $key ) and status=1 order by id desc");
```

How to write laravel model based in this query with pagination???

Comment: you want to write eloquent query or create a model?

Comment: Only query I have Model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for dynamic array:

```
Post::where(function ($query)  use ($keyskill) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($keyskill); $i++) {
                if ($i == 0) {
                    $query->where('skills' , 'like' ,"%$keyskill[$i]%");
                } else {
                     $query->orWhere('skills' , 'like' , "%$keyskill[$i]%");
                }
            }
})->where('status' , 1)->orderBy('id' , 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Post::where('skills' , 'like' , '%php%')->orWhere('skills' , 'like' , '%javascript%')->where('status' , 1)->orderBy('id' , 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Eloquent Query considering Post as your Model Name and Page Size 50.

```
$posts = \App\Post::where('skills','like','%javascript%')
                  ->orWhere('skills','like','%php%')
                  ->where('status',1)
                  ->orderBy('id','desc')
                  ->paginate(50);
```

Loading records

```
$posts->items();
```

Rendering Pagination on Blade

```
{!! $posts->render() !!}
```

Just a recommendation
Your table name should be `posts` instead or `post` then Laravel can manage it implicitly but in your case currently you will have to  mention the table name in your model with code `protected $table = 'post';` in your **app/post.php** file, read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions).

Comment: Thanks,
But actually keyskill dynamic array.